# How to restart a specific network interface by powershell

Tags: networking, powershell, network-interface

I'm trying to restart a network interface by powershell with a specific IP address. I did the following statements:

```
$iface = Get-NetIPAddress | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.IPAddress -like "10.212*" } | format-wide -Property InterfaceAlias
```

Got the interface with format-wide but using the variable below things not working properly.

```
Restart-NetAdapter -Name $iface
```

Is it the right way to use the variable?

Using powershell version 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formatting cmdlets return strings, which are very nice for humans to read, but are no longer the actual objects. In particular, `Format-Wide` adds several linebreaks that are probably confusing `Restart-NetAdapter`.

The objects produced by `Get-NetIPAddress` have an `InterfaceIndex` property that we can use to acquire a network adapter object from `Get-NetAdapter`. Then the adapter object can be piped into `Restart-NetAdapter`.

```
Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceIndex (Get-NetIPAddress | ? {$_.IPAddress -like '10.212.*'}).InterfaceIndex | Restart-NetAdapter
```

Also note the aliasing of `Where-Object` into `?` - this is a convenient standard PowerShell alias that you can use if you like.